# How to tell JSDoc I am extending templated class with specific type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I need some wrapper classes for converting values from XML to javascript and back. The setup looks like this:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * */
class Value {
    /**
     *
     * @param {Element} valueNode
     */
    constructor(valueNode) {
        this.node = valueNode;
    }
    /** @type {T} **/
    get value() {
        return this.node.hasAttribute("value") ? this.convertToJS(this.node.getAttribute("value")) : null;
    }

    /**
     * Must be overriden and provide JS object/variable from the string value
     * @param {string} stringValue
     * @returns {T}
     */
    convertToJS(stringValue) { }

}

/**
 * @class
 * @extends Value<boolean>
 * */
class BoolValue extends Value {
    /**
     * Must be overriden and provide JS object/variable from the string value
     * @param {string} stringValue
     * @returns {T}
     */
    convertToJS(stringValue) { return stringValue == "true"; }
}
```

When I have an instance if `BoolValue`, I'd like visual studio to know that `myVar.value` is a `boolean`.

How to tell JSDoc that a class extends a templated class with specific type?

Answer (score -1):

I probably did not understand the question, but

> When I have an instance if `BoolValue`, I'd like visual studio to know that `myVar.value` is a `boolean`.

works fine with your current setup :D

[image]